# akka + play dependency issue using sbt assembly

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt assembly to try and take our application and create 'one big jar' to deploy it.

I am having a problem where Play 2.1.2 depends on scala-stm 0.6 and akka-transactor 2.1.4 depends on scala-stm 0.7.

I am able to run the app in SBT without issue (as well as Eclipse and IntelliJ)

I am unclear how to resolve this issue using 'sbt assembly'

Here is some output explaining exactly what I am seeing (snipped some stuff):

```
[NPL-play] $ assembly
...

[info] Including from cache: akka-testkit_2.10-2.1.4.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-stm_2.10.0-0.6.jar
...

[info] Including from cache: spray-httpx-1.1-M7.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-stm_2.10-0.7.jar
...

[info] Including from cache: scala-library.jar
[info] Including from cache: voltdbclient-2.7.2.jar
[warn] Merging 'public/plugins/colreorder/docs/media/license' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'public/plugins/colvis/docs/media/license' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'public/images/icons/color/readme.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'public/plugins/flot/LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'public/plugins/photoswipe/README.md' with strategy 'rename'
[error] (NPL-util/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/worms/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10.0/jars/scala-stm_2.10.0-0.6.jar:scala/concurrent/stm/ccstm/CCSTMRefs.class
[error] /Users/worms/ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10/jars/scala-stm_2.10-0.7.jar:scala/concurrent/stm/ccstm/CCSTMRefs.class
[error] (NPL-admin/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/worms/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10.0/jars/scala-stm_2.10.0-0.6.jar:scala/concurrent/stm/ccstm/CCSTMRefs.class
[error] /Users/worms/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.10/jars/scala-stm_2.10-0.7.jar:scala/concurrent/stm/ccstm/CCSTMRefs.class
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Aug 1, 2013 4:09:09 PM
[NPL-play] $
```

If I look at the dependency tree I see the two things that have the conflicting dependencies (trimmed a bunch of stuff out):

```
[NPL-play] $ dependency-tree
[info] Updating {file:/Users/worms/dev/npl/}NPL-util...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/worms/dev/npl/}NPL-util...
[info] Done updating.                                                        
[info] Done updating.                                                        
[info] Updating {file:/Users/worms/dev/npl/}NPL-admin...
[info] Done updating.                                                        
[info] com.myorg:npl-admin_2.10:0.0.2 [S]
[info]   +-com.myorg:networking_2.10:0.0.2 [S]
...
[info]   | | |   
[info]   | | +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-transactor_2.10:2.1.4 [S]
[info]   | | | +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.1.4 [S]
[info]   | | | | +-com.typesafe:config:1.0.0
[info]   | | | | 
[info]   | | | +-org.scala-stm:scala-stm_2.10:0.7 [S]

...

[info]   | +-play:play_2.10:2.1.3-RC1

...

[info]   |   +-play:play-iteratees_2.10:2.1.3-RC1
[info]   |   | +-com.github.scala-incubator.io:scala-io-file_2.10:0.4.2 [S]
[info]   |   | | +-com.github.scala-incubator.io:scala-io-core_2.10:0.4.2 [S]
[info]   |   | |   +-com.jsuereth:scala-arm_2.10:1.3 [S]
[info]   |   | |   
[info]   |   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.0.0
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-stm:scala-stm_2.10.0:0.6 [S]
...
```

Any suggestions on how to go about resolving this dependency issue?

=========================  EDIT: addition of simpler example =======================

I decided to try and create a very simple application with just Play and Akka. However, I got as far as trying to 'assembly' a simple Play app and am having problems.

Here is my project/plugins.sbt file:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.1")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

Here is my project/Build.scala file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._



object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

        val appName = "dependencyExample"
        val appVersion = "1.0"

        val appDependencies = Nil
        val appSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ assemblySettings ++ Seq(net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings:_*)

        val main = play.Project( appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = appSettings)
}
```

And here is the output I get from 'assembly'

```
[dependencyExample] $ assembly
[info] No tests to run for test:test
[info] Including from cache: jta-1.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar
[info] Including from cache: jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: jul-to-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: logback-classic-1.0.7.jar
[info] Including from cache: config-1.0.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: commons-codec-1.3.jar
[info] Including from cache: async-http-client-1.7.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: joda-time-2.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: httpclient-4.0.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar
[info] Including from cache: play-exceptions-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-io-core_2.10-0.4.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: httpcore-4.0.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: logback-core-1.0.7.jar
[info] Including from cache: jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-io-file_2.10-0.4.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: play-iteratees_2.10-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: joda-convert-1.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar
[info] Including from cache: netty-3.5.9.Final.jar
[info] Including from cache: ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-stm_2.10.0-0.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: akka-slf4j_2.10-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: play_2.10-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: sbt-link-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: templates_2.10-2.1.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-library.jar
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/worms/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
[error] /Users/worms/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.class
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 6, 2013 3:07:27 PM
[dependencyExample] $
```

It is still not clear to me how I can resolve this issue. I suspect if I can resolve this simple test issue then I can resolve the Akka + Play issue.

===================  EDIT: different way of accomplishing the same thing =================

I found a 'magical' sbt command with play. 'dist'. This packages up the application in a .zip file and can then be extracted and run on any machine that has java installed.

Here is the blog post at coursera that we found the tidbit on:

http://betacs.pro/blog/2013/08/03/deploying-play-apps/

More information can be found here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist

Answer (score 1):

You can [exclude transitive dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management#exclude-transitive-dependencies). In this case I'd remove the 0.6 version and leave 0.7, as it's newer.

Comment: Hi Luciano. I appreciate your response, however I am still having difficulty :( I have added a simpler example that is exhibiting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a 'magical' sbt command with play. 'dist'. This packages up the application in a .zip file and can then be extracted and run on any machine that has java installed.

Here is the blog post at coursera that we found the tidbit on:

http://betacs.pro/blog/2013/08/03/deploying-play-apps/

More information can be found here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist